# Backbone.js fetch() returning object instead of child in server instance but in local instance retrieves child

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have 2 instances. My local with OS Win7, and a Server instance with OS Linux.

I am fetching the JSON data and setting it to a model using following code.

```
var RModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
                    idAttribute: 'name',
                    parse: function (response) {
                        return {
                            'name': response.name,
                            'title': response.title,
                            'description': response.description,
                            'parameters': new ParamsList(response.parameters)                                
                        };
                    }    
                });
                that.model = new RModel();
                that.model.url = "url/" + '?limited=false';
                that.model.fetch({
                    cache: false
                }).done(function() {
                    that.headerTemplate = that.headerTemplateEdit;
                    that.bodyTemplate = that.bodyTemplateEdit;
                    that.footerTemplate = footerTemplate;
                    that.load({});
                });
```

In my local instance the result of following code in console.

```
this.model
    child
    _changing:false
    _pending:false
    _previousAttributes:Object
    attributes:Object
    changed:Object
    cid:"c217"
    id:"testUndefinedParam"
    url:"/url?limited=false"
    __proto__:
    Backbone.Model
```

In server instance

```
this.model
        i
    _changing: false
    _pending: false
    _previousAttributes: Object
    attributes: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c25920"
    id: "testDateError2"
    url: "/url?limited=false"
    __proto__: t.Model
```

If anyone came across this issue please show some way retrieve JSON data properly.

Comment: What issue are you having with retrieving data?  The data is inside models attributes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the code in your server is processed (minify/uglify) and the code in your local is not. So the processor just renamed `child` to `i`, `Backbone` to `t` etc. You should be concerned about differences in actual data rather than the constructor names the console outputs. As far as I know there is no standard and it can vary between browsers

Comment: `child` comes from Backbone itself. It's the [`extend` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/4a02b5fc3d9759ed8d3180b37cd982c8b30f8696/backbone.js#L1981-L2007) which gives it this name.